# How to add a field at the end of the pdf in Java (PDFBox)

Tags: java, docusignapi, pdfbox

I have documents of different number of pages. My requirement is to add a Signature field at the bottom of the document.
It should be something like below. The page number is dynamic so it can be any number from 1 to 15.

Signature: ______________________

I am going to add DocuSign tabs here.

Any help is appreciated.

---

### Update

I was able to add the field using auto-tagging but the DocuSign tab is displaying over the text instead of replacing it.
I have attached the image below. Is there a way to replace the text ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0e6fG.png)

Comment: Why the PDFBox label if you're doing docusign?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Maybe he is using PdfBox to add the *ocuSign tabs?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I am generating the PDF and sending it to DocuSign via API call.
I thought of adding the above mentioned field and then specify its position as DocuSign tabs

Comment: PDFBox is the name of the software. Are you using that software or is it because your field is a "box"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an anchor string to place a SignHere tab anywhere that a certain string appears in your document. You could use the word "Signature" or use another unique string in white text where you want the Signature to appear. We have a few resources on anchor tagging:

Blog post: https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/tabs-deep-dive-placing-tabs-documents

Developer Center guide: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/tabs/auto-place/

How-to guide using anchor tagging: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-in-app-embedded/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not using DocuSign SDK rather calling Rest API.
I am trying to add a Signature field while generating PDF and then get the position of the field to add DocuSign tab there

Comment: it worked. Only thing is the text is not replaced, rather the tab is displayed over the text

Comment: You can set the anchorHorizontalAlignment property to "right" to align the tab with the last character in the anchor string. Then you may want to use the anchorXOffset or anchorYOffset properties to create some space between the string and the tab. You can see an example of this in the JSON in this blog post: https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/tabs-deep-dive-checkboxes-and-radio-groups

Answer (score 0):

Paige gave a very good answer, let me just add a few things.
You can determine how many pages are in the document, and then use this number to place one in the last page.
See this blog post on how to do this - https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/common-api-tasks-adding-initials-each-page-each-document-your-envelope
The java code is this:
(note this uses a different tab, but you get the idea)

```
    // You need to obtain an access token using your chosen authentication flow 
    Configuration config = new Configuration(new ApiClient(basePath));
    config.addDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
    EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(config);
    
        EnvelopesApi.GetEnvelopeOptions options = 

envelopesApi.new GetEnvelopeOptions();
    options.setInclude("documents,recipients");
    Envelope env = envelopesApi.getEnvelope(accountId, envelopeId, options);
    for (Signer signer : env.getRecipients().getSigners())
      {
      signer.setTabs(new Tabs());
      signer.getTabs().setInitialHereTabs(new java.util.List<InitialHere>());
      for (EnvelopeDocument doc : env.getEnvelopeDocuments())
        {
          for (Page page : doc.getPages())
          {
          int width = Integer.parseInt(page.getWidth());
          int height = Integer.parseInt(page.getHeight());
          InitialHere initial = new InitialHere();
          // 100 pixels higher and to the left from the top bottom corner
          int x = width - 100;
          int y = height - 100;
          initial.setXPosition(x.toString());
          initial.setYPosition(y.toString());
          initial.setPageNumber(page.getSequence());
          initial.setDocumentId(doc.getDocumentId());
          initial.setRecipientId(signer.getRecipientId());
          signer.getTabs().getInitialHereTabs().Add(initial);
          }
        }
      envelopesApi.createTabs(accountId, env.getEnvelopeId(), signer.getRecipientId(), signer.getTabs());
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not using DocuSign SDK rather calling Rest API.
I am trying to add a Signature field while generating PDF and then get the position of the field to add DocuSign tab there

Comment: You can still do the same thing Paige suggested using JSON

Comment: Using anchor tags

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to add an additional document which would only have one page. This would be the "Signing page" and would reference the other pages.

You can include more than one document in your signature request. The documents are sent in an array, the documents will be presented in the array's order.

Example JSON fragment:

```
...
    "documents": [
      {
        "name": "Example document",
        "fileExtension": "pdf",
        "documentId": "1",
        "documentBase64": "<base64 encoded doc contents>"
      },
      {
        "name": "Signature page",
        "fileExtension": "pdf",
        "documentId": "2",
        "documentBase64": "<base64 encoded doc contents>"
      }
    ],
...
```